# React DND - EndDrag - Chrome

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

I'm struggling to use the DragLayer (React DND 2.4.0, 2.4.1 backend) within a Chrome browser (58.0.3029.110), however this appears to work correctly in Firefox (53.0.3).

I'm finding that if I create a DragLayer that is the same dimensions as the DragSource the endDrag fires almost immediately after drag commences.

If the dragLayer is smaller, as long as the MouseDown Event relative position   to the DragSource div, is outside the same bounds, the preview generates correctly and drag operation works as expected.

I am assuming this is something to do with my drag preview, I have set the `pointer-events: none`, as explained in the [DND Demo](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/examples-drag-around-custom-drag-layer.html).

As mentioned, this works fine in Firefox, any help much appreciated.

Comment: it appears that setting the DragSource to position:absolute gets me half way there, no idea why, makes no difference in firefox

Comment: Another point of interest, the DragSource "handle" appears to be limited to the span elements within the div. Again, this is not the case in Firefox.